# Is the prayer shawl talked about in kabbalah?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, tallit-gadol

Does the kabblah talk about the Tallit?

And maybe give us a deeper meaning behind  wearing it?

Is there a sermon on this topic someone would recommend?
Or Book?

In english(not hebrew,since I can't speak hebrew or read hebrew)

Answer (score 1):

Derech Mitzvoisecha, by the third Chabad Rebbe. It's been translated.
[image: the cover]
If you have a local Chabad synagogue, you can check if they have it there, though, if you wish to buy it on Amazon, I can try and find out which volume.

Answer (score 1):

The late Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan wrote about Kabbalah in very accessible English.

He has a book called [Tzitzith: A Thread of Light](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1879016036). I'd strongly recommend you start there.